# JavaScript form redirection not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For my contact form, which I created with contact form 7 in WordPress, I have coded a javascript footer which upon submission of the form should redirect the user based on the radio button selection in the form. The redirection works seamlessly on my laptop, however, when I open the website on any phone (I've tried multiple different ones and browsers), the redirection doesn't work. The code is below, I would be grateful for any pointers as to why the redirection doesn't work on mobile!

Thank you!

The radio button section of the contact form:

```html
<div class="single-row">
    <b> Options </b>
        <div class="single-row">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap" data-name="radio-899">
        <span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio" id="menuradio">
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="fist">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">first</span>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="second">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">second</span>
            </span>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-899" value="third">
                <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">third</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

The javascript code which I have added to the footer:

```js
const redirect = () => {
   window.open('https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/.../25,'_blank'); 
};

const input = document.querySelector('body #menuradio input[name="radio-899"][value="first"]');
if(input){
  input.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if(event.target.value){
      document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
    }
  })
}
    
const redirect1 = () => {
    window.open('https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/... /30','_blank');
};

const input1 = document.querySelector('body #menuradio input[name="radio-899"][value="second"]');
if(input1){
  input1.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    if(event.target.value){
      document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect1);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect1);
    }
  })
}
    
const inputNotGoing = document.querySelector('body #menuradio input[name="radio-899"][value="third"]');
    if (inputNotGoing) {
      inputNotGoing.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect);
          document.removeEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', redirect1);
        }
      })
    }
```

I am unsure where the error is coming from, I have tried a bunch of java script approaches, however, I think the error is a very simple/stupid one, which I don't see, as I am new to web development.